# CSS Font Face Path in Express App Doesn't Work

Tags: css, fonts, express, font-face

I currently have my fonts in `public/fonts/`

My CSS is in `public/css/`

But, no matter what variations I try with the path or css, I can't seem to load the fonts...

```
@font-face {font-family: trend_sans_oneregular; 
 src: url('TrendSans-One-webfont.eot'),
      url('TrendSans-One-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
      url('TrendSans-One-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
      url('TrendSans-One-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
      url('TrendSans-One-webfont.svg#trend_sans_oneregular') format('svg'); 
      font-weight: normal; 
      font-style: normal; }

.btn {border:none;font-family:trend_sans_oneregular!important}
```

Is the path wrong?  Is there something else I need to do for an express app?

```
//Setting the fav icon and static folder
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.static(config.root + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is this:

```
@font-face {font-family: 'trend_sans_oneregular'; 
 src: url('/fonts/TrendSans-One-webfont.eot');
 src: url('/fonts/TrendSans-One-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
  url('/fonts/TrendSans-One-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
  url('/fonts/TrendSans-One-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
  url('/fonts/TrendSans-One-webfont.svg#trend_sans_oneregular') format('svg'); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the path inside the `src` like the following. Let me know.

```
@font-face {font-family: trend_sans_oneregular; 
 src: url('public/fonts/TrendSans-One-webfont.eot'),
  url('public/fonts/TrendSans-One-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
  url('public/fonts/TrendSans-One-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
  url('public/fonts/TrendSans-One-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
  url('public/fonts/TrendSans-One-webfont.svg#trend_sans_oneregular') format('svg'); 
  font-weight: normal; 
  font-style: normal; }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that already, even with a leading forward slash like /public/fonts/... Yet, it still won't work...

Comment: Check the letters' case of the path.I mean uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: Also change a little thing please. Change this `@font-face {font-family: trend_sans_oneregular; ` into this `@font-face {font-family: 'trend_sans_oneregular'; ` and then check if it works.

Comment: Thanks for still trying to help, but again, it will not work.  I don't even get a 404 message.  It's as if the CSS isn't even attempting to load the font.